# extending std::char_traits for multibyte strings

Tags: c++11

std::char_traits<> are kind of suboptimal for UTF8 (or any kind of multibyte strings) especially if you want to implement case insensitive behaviour. I'm currently thinking about creating a text_traits<> template, like:

```
template<typename CharT> struct text_traits : public std::char_traits<CharT>
{
  static bool eq(const CharT *p1,const CharT *p2)
  {
     return std::char_traits<CharT>::eq(*p1,*p2);
  }
}
```

and similiar functions for lt or find. Now my question before I dive into this: Is this totally silly? Is it conforming to the Standard?
Background: I need something like a std::basic_string_view with more advanced search Options, e.g. "ignore case" - that's why I ran into this)

Comment: You probably will need a full-blown Unicode library such as ICU anyway, at which point the question of character traits becomes moot. The library would either not use traits at all (if it's not a native C++ library) or provide some traits of its own. Of course if you want to build such a library you may have to think about extending character traits.

Comment: I am aware that this will not be a full blown ICU solution. But I could live with std::toupper<wchar_t> (even if it doesn't convert ß into SS and ...). But given this Limitation, the question was: can char_traits be extended this way?

Comment: If you are using `wchar_t` anyway, why not use `std::char_traits<wchar_t>` while you're at it? It will not give you diacritic-insensitive search though,

Comment: Hmmh... I should probably be more precise. I have, for example a big json document which is utf8 and I do not want to double the size due to conversion only because I want to have a  case insensitive search. In a usual json document there will probably be less than 10% non-ASCII chars if any at all. "On-the-fly" comparison would make much more sense to me.

Comment: You don't need to convert all the document. Have a custom iterator that iterates over the document and dereferences to wchar_t (or maybe char32_t; you probably want a character type that works in UCS4). The document itself may well stay UTF-8.

Comment: That sounds like an alternative. A few cons however: I am not very experienced with Proxy iterators; I fear that gets even more complicated with reverse iterators (?); I won't be able to use the handy string or string_view functions (find_first_of etc.) and would have to implement them with standard algorithms. 
But nevertheless: Thanks for the hint. I'll probably go this way.

Comment: That's true, I've had regexp functions in mind when I proposed this. They accept iterator ranges. Perhaps a different type of string view is needed. `template< 
    class CharTIn, class CharTOut, 
    class TraitsIn = std::char_traits<CharTIn>, class TraitsOut = std::char_traits<CharTOut>
> class transforming_string_view;` with all the read-only functions of `basic_string_view`. Perhaps boost can provide it.